# Django: redirect if url was written manually by user

Tags: javascript, html, django, redirect, django-views

Is it possible to restrict user from putting url of page by hand?

Let's say I have two pages - somepage.com/home and someplace.com/other and somewhere in home page is button that redirects user to /other site. I want to make sure that user won't be able to access /other by writing its url by hand. Instead it should redirect back to home page.

Is there maybe some decorator like login_required that I can use? Or maybe I should use some js function?

Thanks in advance for any tips, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the referrer property of the html, if the user goes to other page by clicking the link in your home page, then referrer with point to your homepage. But if the user have manually typed the other page link then the referrer will not point to your homepage.

> Return Value: A String, representing the URL of the document that loaded the current document. Returns the entire URL, including the protocol (like http://). If the current document was not opened through a link (for example, through a bookmark), an empty string is returned.

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

Other, not so efficient solutions :

1. You don't need login functionality ? If you need then simply go ahead and implement one and mark other view as login_required.
   If you don't need that then read point #2.

   2. You can POST some random unique value from homepage button to go to other page. And in other view check for that value. If that value is not found then redirect to homepage. If found, display other view.
      If the user is accessing page by entering the url, that value will be missing those redirection to homepage to occur. One thing to make note of, this solution is not secure. Users can trick the server, if you don't implement is secure enough.

Comment: I've had similar idea but this security breach made me post this question here :)

Comment: Great! It looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a middelware and use it.
First, you need to give each user a group or access to the user.i did this with user_type.
Now you create file acl and make a pack of urls name.

**acl.py**

```
    acl_view_segment_divided = {
        "pack_1": [
            "url_name_1",
            "url_name_2",
            .
            .
            .
        ],
        "pack_2": [
            "url_name_3",
            "url_name_4",
            .
            .
            .
        ],
    }

    acl_view_segment = dict(
        user_type_1=list(
            acl_view_segment_divided["pack_1"] +
            acl_view_segment_divided["pack_2"]
        ),
        user_type_2=list(
            acl_view_segment_divided["pack_1"] 
        ),
    )
```

Now you need to create middelware file:

**middleware.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from acl import acl_view_segment
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import auth

from apps.main.views import page_permission_denied_view


class ACLMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    @staticmethod
    def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return

        current_url = resolve(request.path_info).url_name

        if current_url in getattr(settings, 'ACL_EXEMPT_VIEWS', set()):
            return

        user_type = request.user.user_type

        acl = acl_view_segment[user_type]

        if current_url not in acl:
            return page_permission_denied_view(request)
            or
            return redirect(home_page)
```

added middelware to setting.py

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'yourproject.middleware.ACLMiddleware',
]
```

If you have questions, ask questions in comment.I hope your problem is resolved.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how it works. How this middleware knows if url was put by hand or not?